# Get Index of data point in training set with shortest distance to input matrix with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I would like to build a function npbatch(U,X) which compares data points in an input matrix (U) with data points in a training matrix (X) and gets me the index of X with the shortest euclidean distance to the data point in U.
I would like to avoid any loops to increase the performance and I would like to use the function scipy.spatial.distance.cdist to compute the distance.

Example Input:

```
U
array([[0.69646919, 0.28613933, 0.22685145],
       [0.55131477, 0.71946897, 0.42310646],
       [0.9807642 , 0.68482974, 0.4809319 ]])

X
array([[0.24875591, 0.16306678, 0.78364326],
       [0.80852339, 0.62562843, 0.60411363],
       [0.8857019 , 0.75911747, 0.18110506]])
```

--> Expected Output: Array with the three indices of the data points in X which have the shortest distance to the three data points in U.

My overall target is then to get the label of the corresponding data point using the index which I've got. Example for label input would be:

```
Y
array([1, 0, 0])
```

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: What do you mean by _the shortest distance to the three data points_ - a) the shortest distance to the nearest of the three data points, b) the smallest sum of the three distances to the data points, c) something else?

Comment: I just want to get the index of the nearest of the three data points. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't make it clear - you had already written that you want indexes of X points, but don't say nearest to **what** - a) the nearest U point, b) all three U points, c) something else. Your answer should contain a), b) or c) (and in case of c) specify what else). Remember that when you talk of _the three data points_, it's not known whether you mean X, or U.

Comment: Ah, I mean a) nearest of U point. So, I want an array of indices of the nearest row in X to the first row of U, to the second row of U and to the third row of U.

Comment: The label is just some generic definition. Here is what I have already: 
    distance = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(U,X,'euclidean')
    mindistance = distance.min(axis = 1)
    
    i = np.where(distance == mindistance)
    return i

Mindistance already shows that the expected indices are [2,1,1] , but I can't get it as an actual output of the function. I tried it with np.where, but this doesn't work and i is the wrong output.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have confused your _label input_ with expected output, which unfortunately is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` you already chose a well-suited function for the task. To get the indices, we just have to apply [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) along the axis 0 (or axis 1 for `cdist(U, X)`):

```
ix = numpy.argmin(scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(X, U), 0)
```

Getting the *label* is then trivial:

```
Y[ix]
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much! This fixes the issue & helps me a lot. 
One further question on this: The expected output of the task I'm working on is  [0, 0, 0], the actual output which I'm getting now is [0 0 0]. Is there any way to convert it to a comme-seperated version? I'm just afraid regarding possible compability issues for future function, or is this not making any difference?

Comment: Bitte! - These are just different output representations of the same internal data; are you looking for the `array([0,  0,  0])` format you used in the question? If yes, you get this with `print(repr(Y[ix]))`.